# Proof Help: Showing Divergence and Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

For the question below:

Let $x_1 = \alpha$ and $x_{n+1} = 3x^2_n$
for $n ≥ 1$.

(b) Does $\lim x_n$ exist? Explain.

I proved in the first part that if the limit of $x_n =x$ then $x=0$ or $x=1/3$

In this part, I'm required to show if limit exists or not. I know that for $\alpha=1/3$, limit is 1/3. For $0<\alpha<1/3$, the sequence is decreasing and converges to $0$. And that for $\alpha>1/3$, the sequence diverges

Can anyone please help me formally prove the divergence for $\alpha>1/3$. Any suggestions/hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1 = \alpha, x_{n+1} = 3x_n^2$ then first you form the geometric picture in your mind, which you did correctly. Now, to see what exactly is happening, you must first inspect $x_{n+1} = 3x_n^2$ as a growth pattern, and then ram home the argument formally.

This lemma is our key tool.

> If $0 < \alpha < \frac 13$, then $x_{n+1} < x_n$ for all $n$.

Proof : By induction. $x_1 = \alpha$, and $x_2= 3\alpha^2$, so $x_1 - x_2 = \alpha(1- 3\alpha) > 0$ since both the terms are greater than $0$.

For general $n$, start with $x_{n+1} = 3x_n^2$. By induction, $x_n < x_{n-1} ... < x_1 < \frac 13$. So, $x_n - x_{n+1} $ $= x_n(1-3x_n) > 0$ since $x_n > 0$ (since it's three times the square of something positive) and the other term is positive as $x_n < \frac 13$. Therefore, $x_n > x_{n+1}$ , completing the proof.

> A bounded decreasing sequence converges.

This is easy to see. The candidate for the limit is the infimum of the sequence (as a set). Use $\epsilon - \delta$ and the definition of infimum.

Now, you showed that if there is a limit, it is $0$ or $\frac 13$. But the limit cannot be $\frac 13$ here : we saw that $x_n < \alpha$ for all $n$, so $|x_n - \frac 13| > |\alpha - \frac 13|$ for all $n$.

So, the sequence must go to $0$.

---

If $\alpha > \frac 13$, then a similar argument shows that $x_{n+1} > x_n$ for all $n$. However, here something different happens : if $x_n$ did converge, then it would go to either zero or $\frac 13$, but here neither is possible. Therefore, by my second lemma's contrapositive, $x_n$ must be divergent.

---

If $\alpha = \frac 13$ then the sequence is constant.

---

I leave you to see the nature of the sequence for $\alpha \leq 0$. In particular, you will notice that sign doesn't matter, since the square appears in $x_2$ itself, so this is only a question of the absolute value of $\alpha$.

Comment: You said: $ x_1 - x_2 = \alpha(1- 3\alpha^2) > 0$ since both the terms are greater than 0, what do you mean by both terms greater than 0? Is it because $\alpha<1/3$ And therefore $3\alpha <1$?

Comment: Oh, it's a mistake. I should correct it. Essentially, $1-3\alpha$ is a positive number and $\alpha$ is a positive number , so their product is positive. Yes, the edit is done.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to spend some time absorbing this. Hopefully, I'll be able to get it :)

Comment: Not only will you get it, you will never forget it as well. This is an important step in your pursuit of mathematics. Keep it up, and $+1$ for your question.

Comment: Speaking of which, if I have fully answered your question, then you may either accept my answer, or wait for a better one for a few days before making your decision.

Comment: Thank you, once again! Yes, I've accepted it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the delightful conversation.

Comment: Can you please answer this question as well? If, of course, you have time and don't mind answering it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691712/proof-answer-verification-limsup-and-liminf

Comment: I will have a look at it. Question : Are you availing the offer on my profile page? You may have been visitor number 4000. If so, I will not refuse you.

Comment: I really can't say for sure if I'm the visitor number 4000. Just checked your profile again though and it said 4000 profile views.

Comment: Yes. But that is fine. Congratulations for being the first to avail this offer. In particular, I upvote your other question as well (it is not part of the terms and conditions, but the question is also good).

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. :)